# Unable to retrieve instance from Eureka server using JS client

Tags: javascript, node.js, netflix-eureka, eureka-js-client

I'm having a problem trying to get a service URL discover by eureka.

I'm using [eureka-js-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client) to connect to Eureka and for testing purposes I've created two microservices, I've called it: **ms1** and **ms2**.

What I've tried is:

- Start Eureka server to allow services register into it
- Start **ms1** and register into Eureka
- Start **ms2**, register into Eureka and get **ms1** URL.

To accomplish this I've launched eureka server as a Spring Boot app using `@EnableEurekaServer`. This part works fine, I can access `http://localhost:8761/` and see the dashboard.

Then, in my microservices I've this configuration

```js
this._client = new Eureka({
                instance: {
                    app: 'ms1',
                    instanceId: 'ms1',
                    hostName: 'localhost',
                    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
                    statusPageUrl: `http://localhost:${port ? port : this._port}`,
                    healthCheckUrl: `http://localhost:${port? port : this._port}/health`,
                    port: {
                        '$': port? port: this._port,
                        '@enabled': true,
                    },
                    vipAddress: 'myvip',
                    dataCenterInfo: {
                        '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
                        name: 'MyOwn',
                    },
                },
                eureka: {
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8761,
                    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
                },
            })
```

And the same for **ms2** changing the name.

When I run the project it output `registered with eureka:  ms1/ms1` and services seems to be registered in eureka correctly:
[image]

But now the problem is trying to get the URL of one of the two services. From either of the two services, if I try to get the Eureka instances I always get an empty list.

I have this code:

```
let instances: any = this.getClient().getInstancesByAppId(microserviceName);
let instance = null;
let url = ''
if (instances != null && instances.length > 0) {
    instance = instances[0];
    let protocol = instance.securePort["@enabled"] == "true" ? "https" : "http";
    url = `${protocol}//${instance.ipAddr}:${instance.port.$}/`
}
```

Where in "microserviceName" variable I've tried:

- "ms1"
- "MS1"
- "ms1/ms1"

But the response is always an empty array with this output:

```
Unable to retrieve instances for appId: ms1
```

So, what's the problem? Have I missed something? I think the flow is correct:

1. Start Eureka server.
2. Register services into server.
3. Look for instances in the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my own issue. All was working good, the `ms2` was able to find `ms1` using the code I posted, so the problem was:

My `ms2` file was like this:

```js
EurekaService.getClient().start()
EurekaService.getUrl('ms1')
EurekaService.getClient()?.stop()
```

And it seems like `EurekaService.getClient().start()` does not block until it ends (or is available or whatever), so the client is not up and can't get the instance `ms1`.

Note that the method `getUrl()` has the code provided in the OP:

```
let instances: any = this.getClient().getInstancesByAppId(microserviceName);
let instance = null;
...
```

So I've changed the code like this:

```js
start()
async function start(){
    EurekaService.getClient().start()
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));
    const url = EurekaService.getUrl('ms1')
    console.log("url = ",url)
    EurekaService.getClient()?.stop()
}
```

And works perfectly, the output log is:

```
registered with eureka:  ms2/ms2
url =  http//127.0.0.1:8002/
de-registered with eureka: ms2/ms2
```

So, `start` method is not `async` so I can't use `await` or `.then()`, I have to set a timeout and wait to complete.

I don't know if there is a better way to do this or by the nature of the architecture can't be controlled when is available.

By the way, for me, 1 second timeout is enough.